# Intersection of two unsorted integer arrays

Tags: arrays, data-structures, int, big-o

Given two arrays, A and B, both of size (m). The numbers in the arrays are in range of `[-n,n]`. I need to find an algorithm that returns the intersection of A and B in O(m).

For example:
Assume that

```
A={1,2,14,14,5}
```

and

```
B={2,2,14,3}
```

the algorithm needs to return 2 and 14.

I've tried to define two Arrays with size (n), one stands for the positive numbers and the other for the negative numbers, and each index of the arrays represents the number.

I thought I could scan one array of A and B and sign each element with 1 in the arrays, and check directly the elements of the other array.
But it turns out that I only can use the arrays when I initialize them - which takes O(n).

What can I do to improve the algorithm?

Comment: What is the possible range of `n`? If `n` is large (for example, 2,147,483,647, i.e. `INT_MAX`), then the memory cost is huge. You can do this by creating a map or dictionary from one of the arrays, and then checking each item of the other array against that map. Cost is O(m) extra memory and O(2m) time.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a set:

```
A_set = set(A)
print([b for b in B if b in A_set])
```

The construction of the set happens in `O(m)`, checking each element of B needs `O(m)` time, so the total runtime complexity is `O(m)`.

You will also need `O(m)` space to store the set.

Comment: isn't that O(m^2) since you could check the whole set(A) of each element of B ?

Comment: What makes using the set so fast is that checking if an element is a part of it takes only `O(1)` time

Comment: @AmroAnabtawi If the set is implemented as a hash table, then checking membership is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you can create an array or bit vector of *2n+1* Booleans in *O(m)* time or better, then you don't have to initialize the array before you use it:

1. Create an array *S* of 2n+1 elements.
2. For each element *a* in *A*, set *S[a+n] = false*
3. For each element *b* in *B*, set *S[b+n] = true*
4. Return the elements *a* of *A* for which *S[a+n] == true*

If you can't create that array in that time, then maybe you can use @fafl's answer, although that is only *expected* *O(m)* time unless the set implementation is very special.

Comment: Well of course you can create an array of 2n Booleans in O(m) time. A constant multiple m, of course. The multiple will be 16. But it's not generally a reasonable thing to do, and might be impossible. What if n is 2^63?

Comment: @JimMischel I mentioned this approach because the the OP felt that it would be viable if not for the initialization cost.  Presumably he knows that *n* is not excessively large.  I have no idea what you're getting at with the multiple of 16, but some systems will exact an O(n) cost for allocation -- either they always initialize memory to zero for security reasons, or they may impose a proportional amortized cost in GC.

Comment: The 16 constant was my brain misfiring. Sorry about that. But the size objection still stands.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to be noticed is that there are duplicates in both the sets (I know that's not what set is, sets have unique entries, but the stated example in the question prompt to me that, say it's a multiset). Expecting the n <= 10^6. Build an array from -n to n, which can function as a hash map. '0' be the index for '-n', then 'i' be the index for 'i-n'. Iterate over array A, and on encountering a value, say c, hash[c+n]++. Now take an empty set for the result. Iterate over the array B. For each value c in B, if hash[c+n] > 0, then put it in the result set and decrement the count. Like this one can find the intersection in O(m).

Comment: Why not just build a hash map of size m and be done with it? That's going to perform better than an array of 2n items, especially if n is very large. In any case, it takes O(n) to initialize your array, and then O(m) to find the intersection.

Comment: Sure, Your approach is perfect but my intent was to tell the real insight crux of the problem. Implementation is your area of creativity.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to `manually implement a bit-set` to solve the problem.

For instance:
`min(Array A, Array B) = 1` AND
`max(Array A, Array B) = 14` —
therefore, the bit-set is from `min` = `1` to `max` = `14` and `Array A = :11001000000001` and  `Array B = :01100000000001` — `*(Array A) &= *(Array B) = :01000000000001` which is `2` and `14`.